# send specific text from listView adapter

Tags: android, listview

can somebody help me? i have listView with adapter contains 3 Textviews each. i just want to pass one selected text to the other activity
here is my code :
each listview contain 3 Textviews ("noreg", "name", "imo"). i just want to pass "noreg" to the other activity onItemClick

```js
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        ed = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
        sc = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scanCamera);
        hom = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnhome);
        lv = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.resultList);
        if(getArguments() !=null) {
            word = this.getArguments().getString("word");
        }

        new GetResult().execute();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("word", noreg);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return myFragmentView;
    }

    private class GetResult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, search_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            final int result = jsonArray.length();
                            resultlist = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < result; i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String noreg = jsonObject.getString("noreg");
                                String nama = jsonObject.getString("nama");
                                String imo = jsonObject.getString("imo");

                                HashMap<String, String> datastat = new HashMap<>();

                                datastat.put("noreg", noreg);
                                datastat.put("nama", nama);
                                datastat.put("imo", imo);

                                resultlist.add(datastat);

                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                        getActivity(), resultlist,
                                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"nama", "noreg",
                                        "imo"}, new int[]{R.id.namakapal, R.id.noreg, R.id.imo});

                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("noregister", word);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(stringRequest);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String selected1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("word", noreg);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i just found the problem using that code. i used post method and show the result on listview. let say i got 10 list and i clicked list no 5, the textView shows text for first list instead of no 5. which part should i change?

Comment: you can use position for that like this way `String val =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: it doesn't work. where should i put that code? should i delete TextView c and String playerChanged and replace that with String val or just add that code?